# What do square brackets mean in a type declaration?

Tags: list, haskell, types, io

For example:

```
 r <- query_ conn "SELECT * from test" :: IO [TestField]
```

What does `[TestField]` represent?

Comment: List of `TestField`.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I didn't realize you could have an 'additional' type after `IO`!

Comment: It's not really additional; `[]` is a type constructor of kind `* -> *` just like `IO`; it's just that you can write `[t]` instead of `[] t`.

Comment: if you look at [the prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:IO), it declares `IO a` so IO has always an additional type... sometimes it's just the unit type: `IO ()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, an `IO [TestField]` is a list of `TestField`s in an `IO` monad.

However, a more correct description is that it's an IO action whose result has type `[TestField]` (since the resulting value is obtained only after the IO is performed).

You can learn more about those in the following sources:

[Haskell Hierarchical Libraries - The IO Monad](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.9.0.0/System-IO.html#t:IO)

[LYAH - An intro to lists](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#an-intro-to-lists)

Comment: Right, though I'd avoid saying `IO X` is “an `X` in an `IO` monad”. It's actually _an `IO` action whose result has type `X`_. So, if you execute that action you will get the `X` value, but that doesn't mean the action contained an `X` in the beginning. So for the given example: `IO [TestField]` is an `IO` action whose result is a list of `TestField`s.

Comment: You're right, I added this information to the answer.